# How to check whether a value is present in a vector with a UDF and for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, user-defined-functions

The goal is to create a function that will test to see if a number is in a vector.

For example, you would call it like this: `function_name(3,c(1,2,3))` and it would return `TRUE` since *3* is one of the elements in the function.

My function works when the number is in the vector and it will output `TRUE`, but when the number is not in the vector, it will give the error, "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

```
numCheck <- function(a,b){
  for (num in b){
    if (a == b[num]){
      return(T)
      break
    }
    else{
      num <- num + 1
    }
    if (num > length(b)){
      return(F)
      break
   }
  }
}
print(numCheck(3,c(1,2,4)))
```

Comment: `numCheck <- function(a,b){ a %in% b }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although we can use `%in%` as a built-in function for what you're intending to do, here's how your function can be changed to work properly; we can assume that the output is `FALSE` and if the value was present in the vector, then our function will change the output to `TRUE` will `break` the loop and prints the returns output.

```r
numCheck <- function(a, b){
out <- FALSE
  for (num in b){
      if (a == num) {
          out <- TRUE 
          break}
  }
  
  return(out)
  
  }


numCheck(2, c(1,5,3))
#> [1] FALSE
numCheck(0, c(0,1,5))
#> [1] TRUE
```

When you are using `val in vector` as your iterator, you don't go to the next step by adding to the value. Read more here: https://www.tutorialkart.com/r-tutorial/r-iterate-over-items-of-vector/

You are mixing and matching while and for loops together. Here's another tutorial for while loops: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/while-loop/